# dex2jar.jar file generated contains only appinfo class

Tags: apk, reverse-engineering, dex2jar

I lost my android source code and i am trying to get it back somehow. I have an apk installed in my phone which is the only backup i have. I tried using dex2jar and was able to generate a classes_dex2jar.jar file but when i open it with java decompiler GUI it is only showing one class which is the appInfo class.

[image: Java decompiler result for my app]

Answer (score 3):

After the android studio update feature Instant Run the application source files were saved in slices and to get all the files i had to create jar files of the pieces of dex files in the instant run folder.(instant_run.zip file )

Comment: Where is the instant run folder?

Comment: You have to extract a zip version of the apk, through which u will get drawables classes.dex and an instant_run.zip